# Can we use asp.net SignalR for controlling remote connected devices from some central server?

Tags: signalr

Can we use asp.net SignalR for controlling remote connected devices (not a computer or mobile just a different electronic device having its uniuque mac address) from control server? Server will decide when an alarm is supposed to ring from the device and if user not responded to the alarm then the device should send back some kind of signal or message to central server that alarm was not responded.

Comment: Yes, if there is a SignalR client available for the device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , for this you will have to use a some sort signalr client

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

so what ever operating system you install on the device it should support .net or java